# how to add Blogger Header Image

Tags: header, blogger

I am a newbie in Blogger and minimal skills in programming and web designs. i would like to know or ask how can i add image in my blogger header that turns into a link to my homepage?

thank you very much and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

To Add an image to Blogger header follow these steps:

- go to blogger `design` tab
- Select `Header` link top of your blog widget
- there you can find a link to Browse and attach an image to your header with an image.

you can find here some options to put some text and image or only image such e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to add image and url in header-wrapper using html edit,if you are not into web design,see this [thread](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-add-image-to-blogger-header.html)